# Use dependency injection with specific instance - MS Unity

Tags: mvvm, prism, unity-container

I'm writing MVVM application which based on PRISM.
I learning PRISM in those days and I have a technical question about UnityContainer.

Is there any way to inject specific instance while I using `container.Resolve`?

I will try to explain by example.

Lets register the next types:

```
var container = new UnityContainer();
container
    .RegisterType(typeof(ISomeClass), typeof(SomeClass))

// with string
container
    .RegisterType(typeof(IExample), typeof(Example), "SpecificExampleInstance") 
// without string
container
    .RegisterType(typeof(IExample), typeof(Example));
```

The constructor of `SomeClass` get `IExample` as input parameter.

Now I want resolve instance of `SomeClass` but tell to "container" to inject into `SomeClass` constructor  the instance of `IExample` - "SpecificExampleInstance" (the one which registered at line 3 in the code above) and not the `IExample` - without string (the one which registerd at line 4 of above code - without string)

I'm hoaping that my question clear enough, If not please let me know and I will try to change the formulation.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to use the [Dependency](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660875%28v=pandp.20%29.aspx#cnstrctinj_named) attribute:

```
public class SomeClass
{
   public SomeClass([Dependency("SpecificExampleInstance")] IExample myExample)
   { 
      // work with the service here
   }
}
```